# Merge a flv with mp3 without replacing flv audio stream using FFMPEG

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I would like to merge a flv with mp3 without touching / removing flv audio stream using ffmpeg in php. I tried many commands and none helps. Here is the command I am using now.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "4bpCRRV82x.flv"-i "Someday.mp3" -vcodec libx264  -shortest "output.mp4"
```

But it replaces flv audio with the mp3 inputting.
Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you extract first the video's audio, merge your track with, and then use that command to put back the audio?

Comment: @ITomas Will it slow down the entire process ?

Comment: Well, currently ffmpeg seems to support exactly what you are looking for, see http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output. You should provide more information before an accurate answer can be provided. How do you want to "merge"? I'm assuming both inputs are stereo. Do you want the output to be stereo or 4 channels? Do you want the output to contain one audio stream or two separate audio streams?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard : Sorry for the short note. I want to get output as one audio stream with original video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both inputs contain stereo audio you can use the [`amerge`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) audio filter to merge both stereo streams into a single four channel stream, then use the [`pan`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) audio filter to combine the appropriate channels into a single stereo stream:

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a][1:a]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[a]" \
-map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -shortest out.mp4
```

- The video can be [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (depending on the input video format) as shown in the example if you do not need to re-encode it, but if you must re-encode then see the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide).
- The example uses the native FFmpeg AAC encoder which requires `-strict experimental` (or the alias `-strict -2`). See the [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) for information on other encoders.
- The option `-shortest` will finish encoding when the shortest input stream ends.
- See [Manipulating audio channels with `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) for more examples.
- Make sure you're using a recent version of `ffmpeg`. See the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for builds for Windows, OS X, and Linux.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answered, but I am getting error "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height" when using your code. Please check this for detailed output : http://sharetext.org/vni5

Answer (score 1):

As of the ffmpeg documentation you may use the amerge filter

http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:1][0:2][0:3][0:4][0:5][0:6] amerge=inputs=6" -c:a pcm_s16le output.mkv
```

Answer (score 0):

FLV does not support multiple audio streams. Technically is is possible in the binary format by incrementing the stream id. However the FLV documentation says the stream id should always be 0. so even if you did create this file, most players would not play it.